# Project nuget feed in azure dev cannot be accessed from reader

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines

I have created a Project scoped nuget feed in azure dev. I have some developers that I want them to be able to list/restore and read nuget packages so that they can add them in the projects they are working on.
I have added them in my organization (they are using an email address like outlook.com and gmail.com) without any project access and then from the nuget feed permissions I gave the permissions as Readers

When they try to run nuget list they get

```
Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorganizationname/e1f090d9-f848-428b-b774-7fd9dfc873ef/_packaging/Nuget-Test-Feed/nuget/v3/index.json.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found - VS800075: The project with id 'vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/e1f090d9-f848-428b-b774-7fd9dfc873ef' does not exist, or you do not have permission to access it. (DevOps Activity ID: 09410946-865a-4d69-9b05-f1fd1d668891)).
```

Why they are not be able to access this feed?

Answer (score 1):

> Project nuget feed in azure dev cannot be accessed from reader

That is because the Project-scoped feeds inherit the visibility of the project.

So, if the user is not added to the project, will not access the feed.

To resolve this issue, please try to add the user to the project.

As test, I add my test use as Project Readers:

[image]

Then my test user could access the feed:

[image]

Comment: If I add them as Project Readers they can see everything (that includes pipelines, etc...) They only need read access for a project nuget feed